# Prefixing hex value with 0x

Tags: c++, opengl, hex

I'm querying a GL_TYPE in OpenGL and it's reporting back the hexadecimal value as an integer, [as it should](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramResource).

For example: 0x1406 is #define'd as GL_FLOAT but is being given to me from OpenGL in integer form as 5126.

Unfortunately OpenGL doesn't just return the type and it also doesn't just accept the integer (read: hex) value back. It apparently needs it to be prefixed with 0x before being used.

I'm trying to save myself a switch/case and instead cast/convert on the fly but I don't see another way. Do I have any other options? No boost please.

Comment: Do you have a MCVE of this happening?  That sounds bizarre.

Comment: Yes, but it's quite long at this point so I didn't want to copy/paste. It makes sense though. OpenGL returns an integer as my link specified it would and that integer, when converted to hex, is what the type in glew.h is defined as (minus the 0x). Somehow I need to correlate an integer to a hex value without having to make a table of some sort.

Comment: GLint variables don't have a type of hex or decimal, that's just an artifact of how you print them out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear what sort of "conversion" you have in mind:  0x1406 equals 5126.  They're just different ways of writing the same number in source code, and the compiler translates them both into the binary form that's used at runtime.

You should be able to just use the `==` operator to compare the result of `glGetProgramResource` against a constant like `GL_FLOAT`, regardless of whether that constant is defined as 0x1406 or 5126 in the source code.

Comment: I get that they're the same number, but I'm surprised both 0x1406 and 5126 work. They are different bases, and I guess I wasn't expecting a function parameter of type GLenum to be able to switch hit between the two. But I just tested it and it works so I'm happy.

Comment: I guess that's what the 0x prefix is for then... just to signify that "Hey, before using this number as an int, you first have to convert it. So I get what you're saying.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking that the `int` type is inherently decimal, which isn't true.  The CPU actually uses a compact binary representation, and it's the compiler's job to translate the digits in your source code into that binary representation.  The "0x" prefix just tells the compiler to interpret the digits as hex rather than decimal when translating the number into binary form in your executable.  You'll get exactly the same compiled code regardless of which way you write the number in your source code.

Comment: But really, even the binary representation isn't important; you could be compiling your code for some sort of Babbage engine that represents numbers by counting how many holes are punched on a card.  All that really matters is that the compiler understands what number you wrote in your source code so it can produce a representation of that number in the form that the machine expects.  Number bases in source code and number bases in the CPU are completely independent of each other.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for taking the time to explain!